# Getting a specific letter from a string variable for my simple guessing game for clues

Tags: c#

Basically i have a word guessing game wherein the player has a limit of 4 guesses. in each guess i'd like to show a letter of the word to be guessed example:

```
string secretWord = "cute"
```

then for every guess id like a letter to show consecutively:

// First guess

Enter a guess: angry

Clue: c

// Second guess

Enter a guess: charisma

Clue: cu

and so on.

i can do it manually but if i were to change the secret word it would let me manually change the clues again which is a problem, is there a specific function i can use for this?

Comment: What is the question?  How to get the letters in a word?

Comment: ... or are you asking how to loop this?

Comment: well, if the users guesses wrong, show the substring(0, countofmissedattempts + 1) of the secretWord variable

Comment: ...or are you asking how to keep track of which guess/how many letters to show??  Clarity. It is a marvelous thing.

Comment: hello im sorry im new to this i promise ill do better next time :( didnt expect that id get a bad feedback in asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a clue index in the class:

```
int clueIndex = 0;
```

Then when printing the clue letter, you can get the next letter and increment the `clueIndex` like this:

```
Console.Writeline($"The next letter of the clue is: {secretWord[clueIndex++]}");
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for thank you!

Comment: Check this out as for example 
https://dotnetfiddle.net/cs0ntM